# dropdownlist does not select

Tags: drop-down-menu

I’m a newbie and am probably missing something obvious. (see code below) Initializer.cs works because the pull-down items, “Regular” and “Comm”, appear correctly when running Create.cshtml.  However, Create.cshtml does not work: the pull-down fields remain blank while the scalar fields get loaded correctly.

I have spent hours reviewing replies in this forum (and others) and have tried countless suggestions, all to no avail.  For instance, several people said the problem was using the same name in the controller and in the dropdownlist.  I’ve made that change and Create.cshtml still doesn’t work.  Here is the code:

```
Models.Flight.cs
public virtual ICollection<FlightType> FlightTypes { get; set; }

Models.FlightType.cs
public class FlightType
{
[Key] 
public int FlightTypeID { get; set; }
public string FlightTypeEntry { get; set; }
}

DAL.FlightInitializer.cs
var flighttypes = new List<FlightType>
{
new FlightType { FlightTypeID = 1, FlightTypeEntry = "Regular" },
new FlightType { FlightTypeID = 2, FlightTypeEntry = "Comm" }
};
flighttypes.ForEach(e => context.FlightType.Add(e));
context.SaveChanges();

Controllers.FlightController.cs
// GET: /Flight/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
ViewBag.FlightTypeVB = new SelectList(db.FlightType, "FlightTypeID", "FlightTypeEntry");
return View();
}

// POST: /Flight/Create
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Flight flight)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
db.Flight.Add(flight);
db.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

ViewBag.FlightTypeVB = new SelectList(db.FlightType, "FlightTypeID", "FlightTypeEntry");
return View(flight);

Views.Flight.Create.cshtml
<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model=>model.AircraftModels)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.DropDownList("AircraftModelID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.AircraftModelVB)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AircraftModels)
</div>
```

Many thanks for any suggestions.